# i have an error on access database no value given for one or more parameters

Tags: vba, ms-access

```
   'sql = "select * from tblProduct Order by ProductID"
       Sql = "SELECT tblProduct.PID, tblProduct.ProductID, tblProduct.ProductName, tblProduct.SubcategoryID, tblProduct.Description, tblProduct.CostPrice, tblProduct.SellingPrice, tblProduct.Discount, tblProduct.VAT, tblProduct.OpeningStock, tblProduct.Pic FROM tbSubcategory INNER JOIN tblProduct ON tbSubcategory.SubcategoryID = tblProduct.SubcategoryID"
        .CursorType = adOpenDynamic
        .CursorLocation = adUseClient
        .LockType = adLockOptimistic
        .Open Sql, cn, , adCmdText
```

Comment: Did you check for typos?

Comment: This typically indicates a missing or misspelled table or field name.

Comment: @iDevlop i got this error                                        Set lstLocation.Recordset = rs

Comment: @twebazehillary there is no such instruction in your provided code. You should clarify your question

Comment: @iDevlop    PLEASE help me with this code error .Open Sql, cn, , adCmdText     its in the last line